# Sequelize age validation (from birthdate)

Tags: javascript, validation, date, sequelize.js

I want my users to be older than 8 when they sign up.
I followed that example to create my own validator: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-definition.html#validations.
Here it is:

```js
// In a model file 

module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  return sequelize.define('Utilisateur', {
    // ...
    DateNaissance: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      validate: {
        isOldEnough(value) {
          let ageCheck = new Date(Date.now());
          ageCheck.setFullYear(ageCheck.getFullYear-8);
          if (ageCheck < value) {
            throw new Error('Too young');
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, {
      timestamps: false
    });
}
```

The thing is, when I try to sign up this user, it works whereas it shouldn't :

```
{
    "email": "test@test.com",
    "password": "12345678",
    "prenom": "prenomTest",
    "nom": "nomTest",
    "dateNaissance": "2018-03-03", // <<--
    "nomVillage": "villageTest",
    "NPA": "9999",
    "noRue": 42,
    "nomRue": "Chemin du test"
}
```

I also wonder if it can really be done using Sequelize models, given that the model definition will be done just one time ?! Perhaps I must do this check in a trigger ?

Comment: `new Date(Date.now())` can be simply `new Date()`. Note that this includes the current time in the date, if you want to compare just the date part, zero the hours.

Comment: @RobG ~~The~~ thing is when using `new Date(Date.now())` it creates an Date object : `now: Tue Apr 16 2019 12:17:53 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`. But when I only use `Date.now()` I only have the numerical value `1555409996861`. And I need the **object** one to use methods to get yeare more easily ~~

Comment: Which is why I suggested using `new Date()`, not `Date.now()`. ;-)

Comment: Sorry, I must be tired. Thanks it works nice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to do it with **hooks** (beforeCreate) :

```js
// ...
DateNaissance: {
      type: Sequelize.DATEONLY,
      validation: {
        isDate: true,
      }
    }
  }, {
      timestamps: false,
      hooks: {
        beforeCreate: function (user, options) {

          let ageCheck = new Date();
          ageCheck.setFullYear(ageCheck.getFullYear() - 8);
          let birthDate = new Date(user.DateNaissance);
          if (ageCheck < birthDate) {
            throw new Error('Too young');
          }
        }
      }
    });
}
```

[hooks doc](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/hooks.html)